# Get cookie on host

Tags: php, cookies

I set cookie like this: name="example" and get this cookie with

```
$st = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["name"]);
```

When I run it on my localhost, it runs correctly.
But when I deploy it on my host, it can't get the cookies.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't get the cookies?' Are they not set? Are they empty?

Comment: I mean I can't get the cookie on my host, not localhost

Comment: Isn't it getting created at all or is it empty? Are you sure that no privacy setting is preventing the cookie from being created? Are cookies disabled at the web server?